# Which email template is used in workflow in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

In my organization a work flow is running on Case Resolution which send an email. In email it show subject and email body but in workflow there is only subject is written. It mean a template is used in body of email. How I can check that which template is used in workflow.
If anyone has an idea please share with me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a screen shot of the workflow configuration and of the workflow's e-mail definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation I think following is the answer for your question.

Open the workflow and find the step which is sending the email.

In Activated workflow it should look like following:

[image]

In Deactivated workflow, step should be like following.

[image]

If it says **"Create new message"**, it means email body and subject line is configured inside the workflow. Otherwise you will see the name of the email Template. For email details, click on "view properties"